# Help Splitting 2 Three Way Switches To 2 Lights On 1 Circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

In my basement I have 2 light switches and 2 ceiling lights (located in the hallway and laundry room). Presently both switches control both lights simultaneously, as in if the hall light is on the laundry room light is on also, and the lights can be turned off and on from either the hallway or laundry room. I'm trying to replace the old ceiling light in the laundry room with a motion-activated light, but that would require separating the lights so the hallway switch can no longer control the laundry room light (as the motion-activated light needs constant power). I'm usually pretty decent with replacing switches and outlets but I see so many wires that don't make sense it's confused the hell out of me. I gave up trying to figure it out and hooked up the new light the same way as the old light (I thought) but now none of my lights work -_-

I've attached pictures. if anyone could give me some advice, I'd appreciate it!

[image: Switch #1]

[image: Switch #1 to Light #1]

[image: Light #1 to "box"]

[image: "Box" between Light #1 and Light #2]

[image: Light #2]

[image: Switch #2]

Comment: Which location are you trying to install the motion-activated fixture at? Also, can you post photos of the *insides* of the Light 1 box please, as well as the intermediate box? We can't tell much at all looking at them from the outside...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. With the walls open, would you draw a diagram of the wires so we don't have to?